# GetText() inside tag giving two values

Tags: selenium, xpath

```
<span>Hello 
<div style="color:#989898;margin-left:19%;margin-top:-7%; margin-bottom:-3%;> (Your Profile) </div>
</span>
```

If I use get text() fun in selenium..

I am expecting **Hello** only...
But I am getting **Hello (Your Profile)** both the value....

Why is this happening may I know the reason?
How to handle it?
Is there any way of getting only **Hello** by using xpath or any methods?

Answer (score 0):

The correct xpath expression to get only `Hello` is

```
//span/text()
```

With selenium, something like this should work:

```
driver.find_element_by_xpath("//span").text
```